# 2D Lidar serial to USB connections

Tags: lidar, usb, rplidar

I am trying to use the **2D Lidar** of a vacuum cleaner for some SLAM application on Jetson. I opened up the enclosure and noticed there are only 4 connection ports:

**RX, PWM, GND, P5V**

I am now puzzled on where the "**TX**" is, how the scan data gets to the
board, and in general how I can use a UART-to-USB adapter to connect this LiDAR to the computer.

I would appreciate it if anyone can guide me on what USB adapter I can buy and how to make the connection. My goal is to use this LiDAR in ROS (I hope it is a LiDAR that works with http://wiki.ros.org/rplidar).

P.S. I have no idea what brand this 2D Lidar is. In the picture, the LiDAR is surrounded by three buttons which I also don't know why they are there as there is no way to change their state.

[image: RPLiDAR Connections]

Comment: I suspect the RX is the line with serial data on and it receives it from the processing electronics in the spinning part, so it is the RX line for that board and it likely leaves the PCB as well.  Do you have access to any electronics equipment to see what shows up on that pin?

Comment: To get this work I suspect you need to supply the PWM signal to the PCB, but it may send some identification data on the serial port on power up, so maybe you can get some useful info prior to worrying about the PWM control.